# Javascript text file reader doesnt work the first time

Tags: javascript, text, iframe

I got a webpage with some homemade search engine which is supposed to look for some data in a server-side text file. I use JS to parse this file, it works well except for the very 1st time I use it... The culprit seems to be my fetchText() function which doesnt return anything the first time. Note that if I add a alert() inside the fetchText() it works correctly (see note in JS source code). I guess the IFRAME is not fully loaded or something. What can I do ?

**Webpage code**

```
        <form style="margin-top:15px; margin-left:15px;width:200px;">
            <input type="text" value="NGR_" id="srcTxtInput" style="margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px;width:100px;"/>
            <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="SearchString('./Coordinates.txt')" />
        </form>


    <div id="searchResults" style="vertical-align:right;margin-top:25px;"> 
        <select size="4" id="select_list" onchange="Selec_change();" ondblclick="Selec_change();" style="visibility: hidden; width:250px;margin-left:8px;" ></select>                       
        <img id="closeImg" src="./close.png" height="15px" width="15px" style="opacity:0.5;visibility:hidden; margin-left:235px;margin-bottom:5px;margin-top:5px;vertical-align:top;" alt="Close results" title="Close results"  onclick="HideSearch();" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';"/>
    </div>
```

**JS code**

```
function SearchString(txtFile){
    var slist = document.getElementById('select_list');
    var str = trim(document.getElementById('srcTxtInput').value.toUpperCase()); 

    if(str == "" ){
      slist.options.length = 0; //empty list
      HideSearch();
      exit;
    }  

    var txt = fetchText(txtFile); 

//DO SOMETHING
}



function fetchText(txtFile) {

var d = document;
var txtFrame = d.getElementById('textReader');
txtFrame.src = txtFile;

 **//Note that if I add *alert(txtFrame.src)* here the function works the 1st time**

var text = '';
if (txtFrame.contentDocument) {
    var d = txtFrame.contentDocument;
    text = d.getElementsByTagName( 'BODY')[ 0].innerHTML;
}
else if (txtFrame.contentWindow) {
    var w = txtFrame.contentWindow;
    text = w.document.body.innerHTML;
}   

return text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since loading page content like that is an asynchronous operation, you can't expect the contents to be there immediately after setting the "src" attribute of your `<iframe>`.  You'll have to put the code that searches through the text in a "load" event handler on the frame document.

That means you'll write something like:

```
  fetchText(textFile, function(theText) {
    // DO SOMETHING
  });
```

and modify "fetchText()" to be more like this:

```
function fetchText(txtFile, whenLoaded) {  
  var d = document;
  var txtFrame = d.getElementById('textReader');

  txtFrame.onload = function() {
    var text = '';
    if (txtFrame.contentDocument) {
      var d = txtFrame.contentDocument;
      text = d.getElementsByTagName( 'BODY')[ 0].innerHTML;
    }
    else if (txtFrame.contentWindow) {
      var w = txtFrame.contentWindow;
      text = w.document.body.innerHTML;
    }

    whenLoaded(text);
  };

  txtFrame.src = txtFile;
}
```